# Is there any way to write this code with List comprehension in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What should be the correct way of writing this List Comprehension for calculating the value for **result**?

```
    nothing = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    box = [1,2]
    boxes = [box,box,box]
    page = [boxes,boxes]
    pages = [page, page]
    npr = [nothing, pages]

**result =  [box for box in npr.pages[i].boxes] where i is the counter variable**
```

P.S. This is pseudocode.

Comment: it is not really clear, but you do not need any loop, only: `npr[1][0]`

Comment: You've reused/overwritten the `boxes` variable in your `for` loop so it's not clear what you are doing or intend

Comment: This will always return the content of `boxes` in to another array. You could copy the `boxes` in to `result` as well.

Comment: Hi @mozway I have edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @shantanurahut not really, I suggest you take time to think about the question, write it in the most understandable way, describe the logic, include examples of input and output, and ask a new question

Comment: Hi @MSH I have edited the question to be more clear. Can you please help me with this ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
result = [i for boxes in npr[1] for i in boxes]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In this case why not just use:

```
result = npr[1][0]
```

Or:

```
result = sum(npr[1], [])
```

Comment: Hi @U12-Forward. I have edited the question. I hope it is more clear now. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @shantanurahut Please ask a new question instead, I already solved your original problem, ask a new question please, and to close this question, please accept this.